# Reassign function key commands

Tags: function-keys

I used to own a laptop that's function keys had various useful commands, for example, play/pause, fastforward, and rewind, that could control, for example, iTunes.

However, my current laptop does not have any keys assigned to music controls, they are just volume/up down, brightness up/down (etc.), and a few just left blank, with no special function.

Is there a way to give these spare function keys a special function?

UPDATE

It is a Samsung Series 3 501UK notebook.

I have installed all drivers - it's not that the function keys don't work, it's that I'd like to change the special functions they are assigned to.

Comment: What's the make and model of you new notebook? Have you ensured all the drivers offered by the manufacturer are installed?

Answer (score 0):

Search for drivers for your laptop, they should make fn buttons functional.

You can usually download the relevant drivers from your laptop's manufacturer's site. In your case, have a look [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads).